# The binary operator Greater Than is not defined for the types 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The following code throws the `The binary operator Greater Than is not defined for the types 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'` error, although `s.Assessments` is null from the previous code. But, then I do not understand why the binary operator is reacheable even though I control with `s.Assessments == null`. Also, why does it produce `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` to compare with? Any ideas?

```
  baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(s => s.Assessments == null ? false : s.Assessments
                                    .SelectMany(a => a.AssessmentItems)
                                    .Where(ai => ai.RubricItemId == rubricItemId)
                                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    .Average(d => d == null ? 0 : d.CurrentScore) > averageScore.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Comment: why do people consider this off-topic and request to close it ?

Comment: What is the type of `baseQuery` and particularly of its `Assessments` property? How about `averageScore`? Is that error really *thrown* or is it determined at compile time?

Answer (score 1):

When boiled down to SQL, Assessments will not be null, it will be empty. With Linq2EF it is generally a good idea to move your conditional/defaults outside of the expression, then let EF work with values. The risk with having functions and such inside expressions is that EF may not be able to resolve them and raise errors or result in a query being executed to objects early.

```
decimal average = averageScore.GetValueOrDefault();

baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(s => s.Assessments
    .SelectMany(a => a.AssessmentItems)
    .Where(ai => ai.RubricItemId == rubricItemId)
    .Average(d => d.CurrentScore) > average);
```

You shouldn't need all the DefaultIfEmpty and null checks. EF will work through and handle the situations where records don't exist. If the query has no Assessments, that element will not be returned or factored into the average score check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In this case it throwed `Sequence contains no elements` error. It works only if I have `s.Assessments.SelectMany(a => a.AssessmentItems).Any(ai => ai.RubricItemId == rubricItemId)? false : s.Assessments....` check.